# Should we use php5-memcache or php5-memcached when connect with memcached server?

Tags: php, memcached

In php, there are 2 modules that can be used when programming with memcached.

[Memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcache.php) and [Memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcached.php)

In the document, it said that php5-memcached using libmemcached to connect memcached. And there are more function available in php5-memcached module.

Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Take a look at this discussion. It's an extensive one on whether memcache or memcached is better. One reply suggests that memcached is better as there are methods to access error codes. Hope it helps.](https://serverfault.com/questions/63383/memcache-vs-)

Answer (score 0):

memcached is better, but memcache is works too